# JAXB ClassNotFoundException Building Spring Boot App 2.2.0 with Java 11

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb, java-11

I've created a Spring Boot application using version 2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT with Java 11 (POM below):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>Eureka-Service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Eureka-Service</name>
<description>Spring Boot Eureka Service</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

When the app starts up, it throws this exception:

```
2018-12-30 14:09:43.584  INFO 1305 --- [           main] 
    c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec 
   XStreamXml
   2018-12-30 14:09:43.584  INFO 1305 --- [           main] 
   c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec 
    XStreamXml
    2018-12-30 14:09:43.710 ERROR 1305 --- [           main] c.s.j.s.i.w.WadlApplicationContextImpl   : Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.

javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:177) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:364) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:508) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:465) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:366) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlApplicationContextImpl.<init>(WadlApplicationContextImpl.java:107) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlFactory.init(WadlFactory.java:100) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.initWadl(RootResourceUriRules.java:169) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:106) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:744) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:270) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:106) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4511) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5157) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1372) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:907) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1372) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:907) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:933) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:398) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:106) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.orbis.EurekaServiceApplication.main(EurekaServiceApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:70) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1173) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:122) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:155) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:174) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
    ... 61 common frames omitted

2018-12-30 14:09:43.790  WARN 1305 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.a.ArchaiusAutoConfiguration      : No spring.application.name found, defaulting to 'application'
2018-12-30 14:09:43.790  WARN 1305 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2018-12-30 14:09:43.791  INFO 1305 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2018-12-30 14:09:43.922  INFO 1305 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2018-12-30 14:09:44.330  INFO 1305 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2018-12-30 14:09:44.368  INFO 1305 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2018-12-30 14:09:44.368  INFO 1305 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Client configured to neither register nor query for data.
2018-12-30 14:09:44.378  INFO 1305 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1546178984375 with initial instances count: 0
2018-12-30 14:09:44.405  INFO 1305 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Initializing ...
2018-12-30 14:09:44.406  INFO 1305 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : Adding new peer nodes [http://localhost:8761/eureka/]
2018-12-30 14:09:44.583  INFO 1305 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2018-12-30 14:09:44.584  INFO 1305 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2018-12-30 14:09:44.584  INFO 1305 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2018-12-30 14:09:44.584  INFO 1305 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2018-12-30 14:09:44.668  INFO 1305 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : Replica node URL:  http://localhost:8761/eureka/
2018-12-30 14:09:44.675  INFO 1305 --- [           main] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Finished initializing remote region registries. All known remote regions: []
2018-12-30 14:09:44.675  INFO 1305 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Initialized
2018-12-30 14:09:44.682  INFO 1305 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2018-12-30 14:09:44.741  INFO 1305 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application UNKNOWN with eureka with status UP
2018-12-30 14:09:44.744  INFO 1305 --- [      Thread-12] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Setting the eureka configuration..
2018-12-30 14:09:44.745  INFO 1305 --- [      Thread-12] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Eureka data center value eureka.datacenter is not set, defaulting to default
2018-12-30 14:09:44.745  INFO 1305 --- [      Thread-12] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Eureka environment value eureka.environment is not set, defaulting to test
2018-12-30 14:09:44.754  INFO 1305 --- [      Thread-12] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : isAws returned false
2018-12-30 14:09:44.755  INFO 1305 --- [      Thread-12] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Initialized server context
2018-12-30 14:09:44.755  INFO 1305 --- [      Thread-12] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Got 1 instances from neighboring DS node
2018-12-30 14:09:44.755  INFO 1305 --- [      Thread-12] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Renew threshold is: 1
2018-12-30 14:09:44.755  INFO 1305 --- [      Thread-12] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Changing status to UP
2018-12-30 14:09:44.761  INFO 1305 --- [      Thread-12] e.s.EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration : Started Eureka Server
2018-12-30 14:09:44.775  INFO 1305 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8761 (http) with context path ''
2018-12-30 14:09:44.775  INFO 1305 --- [           main] .s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 8761
2018-12-30 14:09:44.777  INFO 1305 --- [           main] com.orbis.EurekaServiceApplication       : Started EurekaServiceApplication in 4.097 seconds (JVM running for 5.186)
2018-12-30 14:10:44.762  INFO 1305 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with compensationTime 0msaa
```

However, when i remove the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

the application fails to start up:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:125) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:171) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:109) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
... 13 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I'm using Zulu 11 and everything works fine. Which Java Version do you use? OpenJDK?

Comment: For me there is no need for `jaxb-api` in dependency. Is there possibly more stack trace for the case not adding this dep?

Comment: I'm using Oracle jdk-11.0.1 the for MAC OS

Comment: Sorry I take it back. Not working for me. Just did notice it still compiled against 1.8.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Starting from Java 9 the JAXB implementation has been removed. So what you have added is only the API and you need to add the implementation also. There might be several alternatives.

As a fix you could add - for example, as there are other implementations also I guess - this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

[Here](https://jesperdj.com/2018/09/30/jaxb-on-java-9-10-11-and-beyond/) is an excellent explanation about this.

Why it has been removed (excerpt from above link):

> Java’s standard library isn’t exactly small and lightweight. In the course of the past 20+ years, many features have been added to it, mostly because at the time it was thought that it would be a good idea if Java supported a particular technology out-of-the-box.
>
> One of these was support for XML-based web services. When Java SE 6 was released in December 2006, XML-based web services were popular, so the developers of the Java language thought it would be a good idea if Java would have support for calling web services as a standard feature. It was decided to add the necessary APIs, that were originally developed as part of Java EE, to Java SE. Among these were JAX-WS (Java API for XML-Based Web Services) and JAXB.
>
> With today’s trend towards microservices, it’s important that the Java runtime environment is small and lightweight, so having a large runtime library with built-in support for every possible technology isn’t as advantageous anymore.
>
> Therefore, a proposal was made in JEP-320 to remove the Java EE and CORBA modules from the JDK.

**Note about MOXy:** you might also need to add `jaxp.properties` that contains line:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

to get rid of problem:

> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.-

Added yet pretty printed version of comment from Orby that contains dependencies for Sun's implementation:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: OK thanks for the explanation.  I've added the following dependencies to my POM and the application has started up OK: `<dependency>
         <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
         <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.3.1</version>
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: Where to place the jaxb.properties in spring boot application?