# Unable to create XML file when using Jakarta XML 3.0+ dependencies

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jaxb

I have a [simple projec](https://github.com/pavankjadda/JaxbBug)t that creates XML file from POJOs. It works fine with `javax` dependencies(2.x), since `javax.xml` packages removed in Java 11, I switched to Jakarta packages. When I run the project I get the error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta.activation.DataSource

**pom.xml**

```
        <!-- JAXB API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- JAXB RI, Jakarta XML Binding -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

uploaded source code to [Github repository](https://github.com/pavankjadda/JaxbBug/) for reference

Comment: Use the `javax.xml` one not the jakarta one. The packages changed for those and that won't work with Spring.

Comment: note; in Apache Tomcat server since version 9 and many other Java packages for other projects  everything has become part of the Jakarta project because Oracle has tightened down on the licensing of "javax" packages in Java. https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaf/   (javax.activation)"Java Activation Framework" now must be (jakarta.activation)"Jakarta Activation Framework"

Comment: @M.Deinum but that was deprecated and no longer supported.

Comment: No it wasn't. The version with the JDK was deprecated NOT the external one (that is quite a difference). The Jakarta one is from JakartaEE **not** JavaEE and simply isn't supported by Spring (and many other frameworks) due to package and dependency changes.

Comment: @M.Deinum If you are referring to this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api and I am currently using this. It got no updates since October 2018

Comment: The fact that it has no updates, doesn't mean it is deprecated.

Comment: @M.Deinum based what I read online, it was part of the Java 8, deprecated in Java 9 and removed in Java 11.

Comment: Again as stated the one that was part of the JVM, **not** the external one. It was deprecated as part of the JVM.

Comment: @M.Deinum Do you have a link for external one? I can't seem to find it

Comment: The JEP itself for removal out of the JDK, nonetheless fact remains that spring simply cannot work with the Jakarta based apis as they simply not support it.

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53978612/6413377). As M. Deinum already wrote few times these libraries just were removed from standard JVM delivery not deprecated anyway.