# jaxb unmarshalling works on eclipse, but fails when deployed

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I have a program to generate an XML based on certain inputs, I have made use of jaxb with Moxy. I see that my code works perfectly on eclipse, but when it is being deployed or when it is being run on the cmd line from the jar, it says the following error

> jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of Jakarta XML Binding-API has not been found on module path or classpath.

I have a jaxb.properties file which says :

```
jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Does it mean that the execution is only restricted to eclipse?
Running a little clueless.

---

Update 1:

dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>XXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectX</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Add the required dependency. " Implementation of Jakarta XML Binding-API has not been found on module path or classpath."

Comment: The same file works perfect on the eclipse IDE, but not on the command line. How is it that the dependencies are different?

Comment: Yeah, because you have the dependency there. You should also deploy the dependency.

Comment: This program is incorporated as an artifact to a microservice environment. The microservice is being hosted in a docker container having openJDK image.  I am not responsible for the deploying, but once it was deployed, there showed errors on my side of the code as I have mentioned

Comment: The error states you don't have the dependency (JAXB implementation classes) on your class path. What version of java and EclipseLink do you have?

Comment: eclipselink 3.0.0 and java 1.8

Comment: Using Maven/Gradle?

Comment: i am using maven

Comment: Just to be sure put the maven dependency part in your question also. Is it like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53978612/6413377)?

Comment: hI, just updated he dependencies in the question

Comment: I think it is as told in comment from Chris. You just do not have the implementation dependency only API. Not sure where it digs MOXY while running in Eclipse. Check the post linked in my previous comment,